Кастомный образ Windows 10
Часто переустанавливаю винду и каждый раз приходится вычищать предустановленный хлам, настраивать иконки на панели задач и устанавливать необходимый софт. Решил сделать кастомный образ Windows 10 на основе оригинального образа от Microsoft.
Единственный способ, который нашёл: развернуть оригинальный образ на виртуальном жёстком диске, запустить ОС в режиме аудита, настроить и захватить полученный образ средствами Dism или каким-нибудь другим способом, после чего заменить install.wim (esd) в оригинальном образе на захваченный.
Этот способ не сохраняет никаких настроек системы, в частности, расположение иконок на рабочем столе, в панели задач, обои и прочую косметику.
Есть ли какой-то другой способ создания кастомного образа? Лет 10 назад их клепали только так. Странно, что единственный способ, который упоминают в сети - вышеописанный.

как задать хороший вопрос. начните с более внятной и конкретной формулировки заголовка.

Аудит не сделает тонкую настройку т.к. вы делаете вручную. Для тонкой настройки (которую вы хотите) используйте NTLite, но она платная. Если нет желания её покупать можно сделать файл-рег в котором будут вынесены все ваши настройки и после установки ОС запускать. После перезагрузки у вас приближенная версия, к вашей - эталонной. Конечно, не так просто сделать файл-рег т.к. многие настройки спрятаны.

Ты хочешь прыгнуть в очень, ОЧЕНЬ глубокую яму. Рекомендации от человека, который паковал ещё XP для конторы с сотней (до 500+) компов - берёшь VirtualBox в качестве эталонного компа и CloneZilla в качестве средства упаковки/хренения образа. Это даст тебе практически неограниченную возможность деплоя и мастштабирования как горизонтульную, так и вертикальную. Да, на начальных этапах будет тяжело, но оно того стоит.

Windows 10 - по факту снятая с производства и сопровождения ОС. Ниже я дам ссылку. Для варианта Windows 10 нельзя отказаться от установки приложений Магазина, а вот для варианта Windows 11 можно (рекомендую не отказываться вовсе, а выбрать минимум - Магазин плюс парочка критических системных).
https://uupdump.net/?lang=en-us
Лично я тоже сборщик дистрибутива Windows 11. Честно говоря, меня немало позабавил рассказ о якобы единственном способе. Этот тот самый способ, который как раз и не нужен, более того, проблематичен по определению.

Не могли бы просветить по поводу других способов? Помимо облегчения сборки за счёт удаления предустановленных программ хотелось бы интегрировать кумулятивные обновления, пакеты, драйвера и пару-тройку своих программ. Как это можно сделать без режима аудита?

Перейдите по ссылке и подготовьте дистрибутив, с теми параметрами, которые нужны, настроив скрипт - сначала с помощью интерфейса на сайте, дополнительно - с помощью параметров в ConvertConfig.ini. Будет всё желаемое, кроме  "пары-тройки своих программ" Но это и не нужно - программы должны инсталлироваться. Драйверы можно интегрировать, но только в случае, если дистрибутив готовится только для собственного использования. В целом это бессмысленно, драйверы устаревают. Дистрибутив в результате интеграции сильно увеличится. На этом сайте есть всё для того, что сделать дистрибутив "под ключ".

Вручную это всё делается с помощью штатного средства dism: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14?view=windows-11. В качестве стартового берётся пустой (голый) install.wim. Я умею это делать и делал несколько лет. Сейчас не вижу смысла пока есть этот сайт.
